# How to tell WCF Client (ClientBase<TChannel>) to pass Kerberos credentials to a trusted server that uses another domain name?

Tags: wcf, kerberos, adfs2.0

I have a setup where our ADFS 2.0 Server uses a URL with a domain name (https://adfs.MyOtherDomain.com) that is different form our real domain (MyDomain.com).

We have added https://adfs.MyOtherDomain.com to the Windows' Local Intranet Zone and both IE and Chrome pass credential without prompting user.

It seems like the WCF Client does not use the sites defined in Windows' Local Intranet Zone.

Is there a way to tell WCF Client to use them or is there a way to provide it with a list of trusted domain names?